# How to fix plus and minus button

Tags: javascript

I have a plus and minus button which add and minus from the total amount a user is to pay, but instead of showing 100, 200, 300 It is just showing 1,2,3.

```
      <div class="second-booking-container">
              <div>
                  <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
                src="./img/shirt.png" /></div>
                  <p class="second-booking-container-icon" 
           name="product" 
      value="100" id="qnty_1">
                      Shirt(s)</p>
                  <p>
                       <button type="button" class="sub" data- 
        target="shirt">-</button>
                      <input type="text" value="0" class="field_shirt" 
               />
                      <button type="button" class="add" data-target=" 
               shirt">+</button>

                      <p class="display_shirt" name="price" max="3" 
            min="1">&#8358; 100</p>
                  </p>
              </div>

              <div>
                  <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
                   src="./img/trouser.png" /></div>
                  <p class="second-booking-container-icon" 
           name="product" 
           value="100" id="qnty_2">
                      Trouser(s)</p>
                  <div>
                      <p>
                          <button type="button" class="sub" data- 
       target="trousers">−</button>
                          <input type="text" value="0" 
         class="field_trousers" />
                          <button type="button" class="add" data- 
          target="trousers">+</button>
           <p class="display_trousers" name="price" max="3" 
         min="1">&#8358; 
           0</p>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>






          Javascript code 
          var subElm = document.querySelectorAll('.sub');
          var addElm = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
          var totalValueElm = document.getElementById('totalValue');

           for (var i = 0; i < subElm.length; i++) {
           subElm[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
           var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
           var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' + 
        targetItem);
       var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' + 
          targetItem);
        var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');

           if (currentValue !== 0) {
          var incValue = currentValue - 1;
         var strValue = ' ' + incValue;
           inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
           displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
        totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) - 100;
        }
         });

       addElm[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
      var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' + targetItem);
       var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' + 
       targetItem);
       var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');
       var incValue = currentValue + 1;
       var strValue = ' ' + incValue;
       inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
       displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
       totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) + 100;
       });
         }
```

Although when I click the add or minus button, It automatically add or minus either 1 hundred when I add once or minus 100 when I clicked the minus button button one, but It displays 1 instead of 100,I want it to display 100, 200, 300

Comment: The format of the code makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding this line:

```
var totalValueElm = document.getElementById('totalValue');
```

In the HTML you provided, you don't have an element with an id of totalValue. Thus, the line below will not do anything.

```
totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) + 100;
```

If you add an element with id="totalValue" then your code should work fine.
(See below)

```html
<body>
<div class="second-booking-container">
    <div>
        <div class="second-booking-container-image">
            <img src="./img/shirt.png" />
        </div>
        <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_1">
            Shirt(s)</p>
        <p>
            <button type="button" class="sub" data-target="shirt">-</button>
            <input type="text" value="0" class="field_shirt" />
            <button type="button" class="add" data-target="shirt">+</button>

            <p class="display_shirt" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358; 100</p>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="second-booking-container-image">
            <img src="./img/trouser.png" />
        </div>
        <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_2">
            Trouser(s)</p>
        <div>
            <p>
                <button type="button" class="sub" data-target="trousers">−</button>
                <input type="text" value="0" class="field_trousers" />
                <button type="button" class="add" data-target="trousers">+</button>
                <p class="display_trousers" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358; 0
                </p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div id='totalValue'></div>

<script>

var subElm = document.querySelectorAll('.sub');
var addElm = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
var totalValueElm = document.getElementById('totalValue');

for (var i = 0; i < subElm.length; i++) {
    subElm[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
        var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' +
            targetItem);
        var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' +
            targetItem);
        var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');
  
        if (currentValue !== 0) {
            var incValue = currentValue - 1;
            var strValue = ' ' + incValue;
            inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
            displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
            totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) - 100;
        }
    });

    addElm[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
        var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' + targetItem);
        var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' +
            targetItem);
        var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');
        var incValue = currentValue + 1;
        var strValue = ' ' + incValue;
        inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
        displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
        totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) + 100;
    });

}
</script>
```

If you also need the "₦ 0" portion to show up as a multiple of 100, you can change this line

```
displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358;" + strValue;
```

to this:

```
displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358; " + incValue * 100;
```

```html
<div class="second-booking-container">
    <div>
        <div class="second-booking-container-image">
            <img src="./img/shirt.png" />
        </div>
        <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_1">
            Shirt(s)</p>
        <p>
            <button type="button" class="sub" data-target="shirt">-</button>
            <input type="text" value="0" class="field_shirt" />
            <button type="button" class="add" data-target="shirt">+</button>

            <p class="display_shirt" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358; 100</p>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="second-booking-container-image">
            <img src="./img/trouser.png" />
        </div>
        <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" value="100" id="qnty_2">
            Trouser(s)</p>
        <div>
            <p>
                <button type="button" class="sub" data-target="trousers">−</button>
                <input type="text" value="0" class="field_trousers" />
                <button type="button" class="add" data-target="trousers">+</button>
                <p class="display_trousers" name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358; 0
                </p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div id='totalValue'></div>

<script>

var subElm = document.querySelectorAll('.sub');
var addElm = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
var totalValueElm = document.getElementById('totalValue');

for (var i = 0; i < subElm.length; i++) {
    subElm[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
        var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' +
            targetItem);
        var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' +
            targetItem);
        var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');
  
        if (currentValue !== 0) {
            var incValue = currentValue - 1;
            inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
            displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358; " + incValue * 100;
            totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) - 100;
        }
    });

    addElm[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var targetItem = this.getAttribute('data-target');
        var inputElm = document.querySelector('.field_' + targetItem);
        var displayElm = document.querySelector('.display_' +
            targetItem);
        var currentValue = +inputElm.getAttribute('value');
        var incValue = currentValue + 1;
        inputElm.setAttribute('value', incValue);
        displayElm.innerHTML = "&#8358; " + incValue * 100;
        totalValueElm.innerText = Number(totalValueElm.innerText) + 100;
    });

}
</script>
```